# Javascript(Jquery) executes in HTML header but not not when in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this stuff has been asked before...but I am a bit confused about this still. I have my index.html file and I have a script tag linking to my external JS file. If I only have that script tag the JS does nothing, but if I copy the JS and paste it into it's own script tag in the HTML header it works just fine. There's gotta be something I'm missing with Jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FinalProjectCss.css">
    <title>Dustin Naylor - Final Project</title>
<script src="FinalProjectJS.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".section").click(function(){
            if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
                $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
            } else{
                $(this).next().hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>

<span class="section"><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">Click Me</a></span>
<div class = "hiddenDiv">
    Oh hey there.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the code in the last script tag that is Jquery stuff is exactly copied into a separate JS file named FinalProjectJS.js. In the current state this code is in it works as desired, but when I remove that chunk of code from the html file it doesn't work....Sorry for my nubishness, I'm rather new and any help would be great! thanks!

Comment: What do you mean its not working ? What error are you getting in the console ?

Comment: If the `FinalProjectJS.js` file isn't loading... then it's not loading! :) What does (as @WilomGfx said) the console say in the example that's *not working*? Can you give us the code example that's broken as well?

Comment: @Dustin Naylor May be path error,please check it carefully

Comment: I have to be brutally honest. I posted this to Github so I could work on it on my laptop elsewhere...didn't end up actually changing anything. Updated my files on my desktop again from github...and now it works. I have no script tag containing my jQuery in the HTML and I have the link to the external file and its working now. I have no idea what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the contents of your *jquery* file: *FinalProjectJS.js*? The syntax for calling the external file seems to be correct. So I'm thinking it might be something about the path or the jquery external file contents itself. Make sure you don't include `<script>` tags on that file. Here's a [sample](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptexternal.php).

Another thing, last time I've worked with jquery, I can't directly see it take effect when both my files are stored locally. It had to be stored in a server first, then accessed by my PC. Only then did my jquery took effect. A dev I worked with added some text to my Google Chrome's properties (target) so that even if my file is not stored in a server, I can see jquery take effect even if both my HTML and jquery files are stored locally.

...sorry, I'm not allowed to comment yet to clarify your post.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the jQuery script tag before FinalProjectJS.js for the jQuery snippet to work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
```

integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous">